# While creating an aliases in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search. Now I've created aliases for 2 index. What is the internal process of elsasticsearch? will it create seperate or it will refer existing index.Seperate index means, will it occupy extra space?

```
 i ve 2 index "index1" and "index2". now i create "indexaliasis" as a aliasis for index1  
 and index2.Now, will the elastic search create new index called in name "indexaliasis" and      
 occupy seperate space, or it ll jus refer two index and search.
```

i am asking because we can have filters in aliasis. when will that filter applied. during search or while creating aliasis.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Could ou please clarify your question? It's hard for me to understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: i edited ma post with clarification..! Thank you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias does not create another index. It's just a mapping.

More Information:

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html